# Онлайн платежи на сайте Django

Tags: django, ecommerce

Очень мало инфы по этому поводу, по пальцам пересчитать.
Интересует как возможно прикрутить онлайн оплату картой к сайту на Django, желательно чтобы была форма для заполнения карты прямо на сайте, но в крайнем случае через redirect.
Есть ли актуальные решения которые были проверены на практике?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "мало инфы"? У каждого платежного агрегатора и банковского эквайринга есть документация.

Comment: Наличие формы для заполнения карты на вашем сайте сделает вас ответственным за утечку данных. Сомнительная желательность.